# Display a block when a view doesn't return any result

Tags: blocks

On node/48, the page is composed from a text and a view. I would like to display a block when the view does not return any result.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After enabling PHP filter module, you could edit the visibility settings of this block and write some PHP there to return TRUE only if this view has NO result, something like:

```
<?php
  $view = views_get_view('foo');
  $view->set_display('your_displays');
  if (!$view->result) {// or another check (empty()..) that will do the job
   return TRUE;
  }
?>
```

or something like that..

Comment: what is the $output = $view->preview();

Comment: removed from code ..

Answer (score 4):

You can call your block inside "No results behavior", using a "Global: Text area" and the "PHP" Text format.
But you won't be able to display it where you want, it will have to be at the same place as the view.